# Find pattern in array of array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

Hi guys I am currently learning Java and I'm trying to make a program that you can use too book motel rooms. I'm trying to create a method to search the amount of days a guest needs and then check the days and units that are free. I'm using a 2D array of an array of an array.

```
    public void doSearch() {
    this.redisplay();
    int daysWanted = UI.askInt("Number of days required"); 
    int days = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_UNITS; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < NUM_DAYS; j++){
            if(bookings[i][j] == null){
                days++;
                if(daysWanted >= days && this.bookings[i] == this.bookings[i]){
                    this.displayCell (i, j, Color.red);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image of motel program]

here is what the program looks like currently, and what i have shown above is the method i am trying to do. What my problem is, when i type in how many days, it checks if the available unit is free for that many days, but i want it to be consequtive. How would i go about this? any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: `if(daysWanted >= days && this.bookings[i] == this.bookings[i]){` this line is incorrect because the second condition is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this :

```
for(int j = 0; j < NUM_DAYS; j++){
    if(bookings[i][j] == null){
        days++;
        if(daysWanted >= days && this.bookings[i] == this.bookings[i]){
            this.displayCell (i, j, Color.red);
        }
    }
}
```

to something like this:

```
days = 0;
int[] daysWeWant = new int[daysWanted];
for(int j = 0; j < NUM_DAYS; j++){
    if(bookings[i][j] == null){
       daysWeWant[days] = j;
       days++;
       if(daysWanted == days){
           break;
       }
    }
    else{
        days = 0;
        int[] daysWeWant = new int[daysWanted];
    }
}
if(days== daysWanted ){
    for(int j = 0 ; j< daysWanted; j++){
        int day = daysWeWant [j];
        this.displayCell (i, day , Color.red);
    }
}
```

If you do this it makes days zero if one day is not avaiable and continue to search again.

Comment: that doesn't work sorry, that just finds a whole bunch of different days @Lrrr

Comment: @NandaArdianto check out my update and change your code, this must work

Comment: This is always true `&& this.bookings[i] == this.bookings[i]`

Comment: `this.bookings[i] = i;

  this.bookings[j] = j;` @Lrrr is this what you meant by  //add i, j to that array??

Comment: @NandaArdianto have an array or a list, and every time a day is free add that day to your list, that array or lists elements count became your desired number is, and if you see a day which date is registered but empty your array and try with next day and so on ...

Comment: @Lrrr so is it a new array for free days or do i just make the day free on the bookings[][] array? I think I kinda understand what you are saying. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @NandaArdianto I changed my code again and convert that comments to code!

Comment: @Lrrr thanks so much, i get it now, thats what i was thinking you were saying. I'm just trying to get my head on arrays atm haha. I'm just fixing up array out of bounds errors now :)

Comment: @NandaArdianto first your welcome, but I have a little mistake in my last `for loop` that I fixed please update your code, also where did you get `array out of bound exception`? And if this answer helped please consider upvoting and marking this as an answer.

Comment: @Lrrr yeah I saw that you fixed it, and i got the error in `int day = daysWeWant [j];` line

Comment: @Lrrr yeah I am, what its doing is it is setting and higlighting the day before the first day too, so the day before monday which is non existence cos mine is only monday to sunday but i havent made it go back a week yet etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Lrrr was on the right path - you need to reset your `days` counter for each unit that you are searching.  Likely you can change:

```
int days = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_UNITS; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM_DAYS; j++){
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_UNITS; i++){
    int days = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM_DAYS; j++){
```

But without sample data, it would be a bit of work to check for certain.

You might find that writing some unit tests would help you a lot in working on this.